# Multi-Line Groovy String in build.gradle?

Tags: groovy, gradle

I use gradle and want to create a String in my `build.gradle` which goes over more than one line to make it more readable.

Here is the original:

```
myConfig {
   myFlags "--no-package-directories --prefixes prefixes.properties -use-arc -classpath ${projectDir}/lib/dagger-2.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:${projectDir}/lib/dagger-2.0-SNAPSHOT-sources.jar:${projectDir}/lib/javax.inject-1.jar"

}
```

I tried to use groovy multi line String but it raises an error when I do the following:

```
myConfig {
   myFlags """--no-package-directories --prefixes prefixes.properties -use-arc 
-classpath ${projectDir}/lib/dagger-2.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:
${projectDir}/lib/dagger-2.0-SNAPSHOT-sources.jar:
${projectDir}/lib/javax.inject-1.jar"""

}
```

**Edit:** The definition of myFlags is:

```
class SomePluginExtension {
    String myFlags = ""
}
```

The error I get is:

```
[sts] Build failed
org.gradle.tooling.BuildException: Could not execute build using Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.3-bin.zip'.
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ResultHandlerAdapter.onFailure(ResultHandlerAdapter.java:53)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.async.DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor$1$1.run(DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor.java:57)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(DefaultExecutorFactory.java:64)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.BlockingResultHandler.getResult(BlockingResultHandler.java:46)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DefaultBuildLauncher.run(DefaultBuildLauncher.java:71)
    at org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.core.TaskUtil.execute(TaskUtil.java:117)
    at org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.core.launch.GradleProcess$1.doit(GradleProcess.java:92)
    at org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.core.util.GradleRunnable$1.run(GradleRunnable.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.exceptions.LocationAwareException: Script '/Users/mg/Documents/Grails/GGTS3.6.2/TestJ2Objc/j2objc.gradle' line: 416
Execution failed for task ':j2objcTranslate'.
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultExceptionAnalyser.transform(DefaultExceptionAnalyser.java:77)
    at org.gradle.initialization.MultipleBuildFailuresExceptionAnalyser.transform(MultipleBuildFailuresExceptionAnalyser.java:47)
    at org.gradle.initialization.StackTraceSanitizingExceptionAnalyser.transform(StackTraceSanitizingExceptionAnalyser.java:30)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:108)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:86)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:80)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildModelAction.run(BuildModelAction.java:43)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildModelAction.run(BuildModelAction.java:30)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ConfiguringBuildAction.run(ConfiguringBuildAction.java:119)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:48)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.DaemonHealthTracker.execute(DaemonHealthTracker.java:47)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:60)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:71)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.HintGCAfterBuild.execute(HintGCAfterBuild.java:41)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:246)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(DefaultExecutorFactory.java:64)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':j2objcTranslate'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:64)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:42)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask.executeWithoutThrowingTaskFailure(AbstractTask.java:306)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.executeTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:63)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:51)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:23)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:88)
    at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:29)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$200(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$2.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:68)
    at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:55)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:149)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:106)
    ... 34 more
Caused by: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Applications/J2Objc/j2objc-0.9.7b/j2objc'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
    at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle$ExecResultImpl.assertNormalExitValue(DefaultExecHandle.java:365)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecAction.execute(DefaultExecAction.java:31)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.DefaultFileOperations.exec(DefaultFileOperations.java:151)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.exec(AbstractProject.java:780)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.exec(AbstractProject.java:776)
    at org.gradle.api.Project$exec$6.call(Unknown Source)
    at J2objcTranslateTask.translate(/Users/mg/Documents/Grails/GGTS3.6.2/TestJ2Objc/j2objc.gradle:416)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:63)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:218)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:211)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:200)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:585)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:568)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
    ... 57 more
[sts] Time taken: 0 min, 0 sec
```

**How can I create a multi-line Groovy String in build.gradle?**

Comment: Actually your code looks correct. Can you provide the definition of myFlags and the error code you're getting? Is it a compilation error or a runtime error?

Comment: It looks like the build did not get executed at all - is this true?

Comment: @AmnonShochot it is not executed when I write the String in multiple lines.

Comment: Can you try storing the multi-line string in a variable (i.e. `def flags="""..."""` and then configure `myFlags` with the `flags` variable?

Comment: @AmnonShochot Could you please post an example for your suggestion.

Comment: I updated my previous comment. My guess would be that passing the multi-line string to myFlags directly causes the trouble, so instead you can define a multi-line string outside the closure and pass it to myFlags

Comment: The application `Applications/J2Objc/j2objc-0.9.7b/j2objc` whatever that is, cannot handle the flags being on separate lines. Try putting `\\` at the end of the first three lines of your multi line string

Comment: Sorry, I meant `\\\`... Ie: two backslashes. Stackoverflow seems to have some sort of escaping on backslashes in the comments

Answer (score 12):

It works for me:

```
def multyline = '''\
--no-package-directories --prefixes prefixes.properties -use-arc 
-classpath ${projectDir}/lib/dagger-2.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:
${projectDir}/lib/dagger-2.0-SNAPSHOT-sources.jar:
${projectDir}/lib/javax.inject-1.jar
'''
```

I hope it helps you)

Answer (score 0):

### Here is your original:

```
myConfig {
   myFlags "--no-package-directories --prefixes prefixes.properties -use-arc -classpath ${projectDir}/lib/dagger-2.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:${projectDir}/lib/dagger-2.0-SNAPSHOT-sources.jar:${projectDir}/lib/javax.inject-1.jar"
}
```

### Here is what I have tried and worked for me in the past:

```
myConfig {
   myFlags "--no-package-directories --prefixes prefixes.properties -use-arc " +
           "-classpath ${projectDir}/lib/dagger-2.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:${projectDir}/lib/dagger-2.0-SNAPSHOT-sources.jar:${projectDir}/lib/javax.inject-1.jar"
}
```

### Most of the time, you can think of `Groovy` just like `Java`:

**Valid `Java`:**

```
String var = "--no-package-directories --prefixes prefixes.properties -use-arc " +
       "-classpath ${projectDir}/lib/dagger-2.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:${projectDir}/lib/dagger-2.0-SNAPSHOT-sources.jar:${projectDir}/lib/javax.inject-1.jar"
```

**Valid `Groovy`:**

```
def var = "--no-package-directories --prefixes prefixes.properties -use-arc " +
       "-classpath ${projectDir}/lib/dagger-2.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:${projectDir}/lib/dagger-2.0-SNAPSHOT-sources.jar:${projectDir}/lib/javax.inject-1.jar"
```

### Go crazy if you want:

```
myConfig {
   myFlags "--no-package-directories " +
           "--prefixes prefixes.properties " +
           "-use-arc " +
           "-classpath ${projectDir}/lib/dagger-2.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:${projectDir}" +
           "/lib/dagger-2.0-SNAPSHOT-sources.jar:${projectDir}/lib/javax.inject-1.jar"
}
```

Comment: I tried what you did as well, but it does not work. Same error.

Comment: Post your entire `build.gradle`, I do not get your error.